# How to include one component data into another component in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to include one component HTML data into another component. I tried a lot but I am unable to get the results.

`</hello> </hello>` is the selector tag of the HelloComponent and I am including into the AppComponent.But its not showing the combined data in app.component.html page.

## app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    htmldata = '';

    ngOnInit(){
        this.createHtmlData();
    }

    createHtmlData() {
        //</hello></hello> is selector tag of hello.component.ts
        this .htmldata = '<p>My Data</p><hello></hello>';
    }
}//class
```

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
    <div>{{ htmldata }}</div>
</div>
```

### hello.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello',
    templateUrl: './hello.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./hello.component.css']
})

export class HelloComponent {

}
```

### hello.component.html

```
<div class="take-action">
    <span class="un_config_link" (click)="takeAnAction()">Take an action on</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You import HelloComponent from hello.component.js in AppComponent but it export only a PopupComponent and your selector is wrong

[edit] you need to add HelloComponent to the module declaration of your app, remove the empty line between your @component block of helloComponent and the following class then it would work I believe.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.Please have look now.Please show me the working example of which will satisfy my requirement.Thanks.